# R, h2o and foreach: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: r, memory-management, foreach, parallel-processing, h2o

In a different post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444333/parallel-processing-in-r-with-h2o?noredirect=1#comment73982530_43444333) I asked for help on parallel processing a call to `h2o.gbm` inside a `foreach` loop.

Following the answers provided, I run a script similar to this example:

```
library(h2o)
data(iris)
data <- as.h2o(iris)
ss <- h2o.splitFrame(data)
gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = 1:4, y = "Species", training_frame = ss[[1]])
h2o.saveModel(path="some path")
h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


#setup parallel backend to use 12 processors
cl <- makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#loop
df4 <- foreach(i = seq(20), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
 library(h2o)
 port <- 54321 + 3*i
 print(paste0("http://localhost:", port))
 h2o.init(nthreads = 1, max_mem_size = "10G", port = port)  #my local machine runs 128GB
 df4 <- data.frame()
 gbm <- h2o.loadModel(path="some path")
 df4 <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(gbm, ss[[2]]))[,1]
}
```

It runs really well on a small sample of my real data (at least 50% faster than sequential)

But when I run this on all of my data, I get the following error code after 45 minutes:

```
Error in { : task 2 failed - "

ERROR MESSAGE:

DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:60984, caused by 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to clean up RollupStats after an 
exception (see cause). This could cause a key leakage, key=$05ff14000000feffffff$_b66dbd609dc068f0137cc88cb42a
"
```

I am not sure what causes this error code. I guess it has to do with a memory issue because this code will take up 85-95% of my RAM (128GB) and 100% of my CPU (12 threads).

Anyone any ideas to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, I found the reason of this error. It is actually really simple.

Using `makeCluster(12)` I request 12 threads on my CPU.

Later on in the `foreach` call, I make a `h2o.init` call in which I request yet another thread.

Since my machine only has 12 threads, this last call for an additional (12+1) thread can't be correctly processed.

I fixed this by assigning 6 threads to the cluster. This leaves me 6 threads to make six individual calls to `h2o.init` (one in each `foreach` call).

This works great.